Braking noise at low speed in dry condition, sound gone on rainy day or after car wash and back again when dry
My front brake makes squeaky noises when braking at very low speed and very low speed only, it's gone when it's wet or a rainy day or when I release the brake. When the car stops, it also makes a grunt noise but only when on Drive mode. If I put the transmission in neutral then release the brake there is no sound, also I notice excessive dust on my tire. My brakes work normally, what could be the problem? The car is Hyundai Tucson 2009. I checked the brake pads and they are still really thick.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is the whine constant at low speeds then goes away while braking? Also, did you check both sides (inner and outer pads)?

When replacing your brake pads, you usually have a choice between metallic, ceramic and organic pads. Each has its advantages and disadvantages. Metallic brake pads tend to be more noisy than the others, so if you have metallic pads now, you may get relief by switching to another style.
You might also try applying shims to the back of your brake pads, either shims designed for your specific pads that clip on, or generic self-adhesive shims. These tend to dampen vibrations that create squealing sounds, and they are inexpensive.
